# count frequency of a value in a mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

thanks for read my question.
i have a document mongo db

```
 [
    {
      "key": 1,
      "data": {
        "first": "juan",   
        "last": "pedro",
      },
      "test":"juan",
      "otherFiled":"juan",
      "other": "maria"
    }
]
```

i need count the numbers of **"juan"** in each document.

the expected result is

```
[
    {
        "key":1,
        "count"3:
    },
]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The property names are different for each document?

Comment: no, but you have many embedded documents

Comment: i change the question. for greater ease

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080413/mongodb-how-to-count-a-field-if-its-value-matches-a-condition

Comment: @DanielLopez How deep are those object properties? Is it always just one level?

Comment: not, usually two or three levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I have something that seems to work but it's kind of *horrible*. The main idea is to convert the whole document to an array and then count the properties which have the value "juan". The middle stages are there just to flatten nested properties (if you need to support more deeply nested properties, just add one of those stages, they're the same except for the first one - I told you it's horrible).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      key: 1,
      asArray: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      key: "$key",
      flattened: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$asArray",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $type: "$$this.v"
                  },
                  "object"
                ]
              },
              then: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    $objectToArray: "$$this.v"
                  }
                ]
              },
              else: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      key: "$key",
      flattened: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$flattened",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $type: "$$this.v"
                  },
                  "object"
                ]
              },
              then: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    $objectToArray: "$$this.v"
                  }
                ]
              },
              else: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      key: "$key",
      flattened: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$flattened",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $type: "$$this.v"
                  },
                  "object"
                ]
              },
              then: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  {
                    $objectToArray: "$$this.v"
                  }
                ]
              },
              else: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      key: "$key",
      orig: "$orig",
      count: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$flattened",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.v",
                  "juan"
                ]
              },
              then: {
                $add: [
                  "$$value",
                  1
                ]
              },
              else: {
                $add: [
                  "$$value",
                  0
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/cSwdjMDXuJk

Comment: thanks for your answer ¿What would happen if I have a array?

Comment: To support array properties, you would have to unwrap each array and concat it with the flattened meta property. Honestly, I think a better way forward would be to rethink the structure of your documents or figure out how to make these queries much more manageable.